# Strings Array error

Tags: android, arrays, string, listview

Tell me how to implement this example, understand with List view , in strings :

```
<string name="ml350">300</string>
<string name="ml400">400</string>
<string name="ml600">600</string>
<string name="ml800">800</string>
<string name="ml1000">1000</string>
```

.

```
public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {
        "300",
        "400", "600",
        "800","1000" };

ListView listView;
List<RowItem> rowItems;

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < descriptions.length; i++) {
        //RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i], descriptions[i]);
        RowItem item = new RowItem(R.drawable.ic_untitled_2, descriptions[i], descriptions[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
            R.layout.listview_item_row, rowItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

the problem is that when I try to substitute:

```
public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {
        R.strings.300,
       R.strings.400, R.strings.600,
        R.strings.800,R.strings.1000 };
```

I receive an error.

Comment: consider making `descriptions` as non-static variable. Just declare the `descriptions` variable. and initialize it in `onCreate()` like `descriptions = getResources().getStringArray(int)`. but here you have just declared `String`s, not a `string-array`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must use:

```
R.strings.ml350,
R.strings.ml400,
R.strings.ml600,
R.strings.ml800,
R.strings.ml1000
```

instead of :

```
R.strings.300,
R.strings.400,
R.strings.600,
R.strings.800,
R.strings.1000
```

and you need:

```
 getResources().getString("your key");
```

for first:

`300` is a value of `ml350`, so you need key of that for accessing the value.

second:

R.string.Key return id of String but you need Value of String so you must access that with `getResources().getString()` method

and better way is create one array and call that in your activity.

**//Edit**

so your code must be like:

```
public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {
        getResources().getString(R.strings.ml350),
        getResources().getString(R.strings.ml400),
        getResources().getString(R.strings.m1600),
        getResources().getString(R.strings.ml800,
        getResources().getString(R.strings.m11000) };
```

and you must call this after initializing your view because this need context of your layout, so if you call before onCreate() you got **NPE**

Comment: Thanks corrected his inattention, but it did not solve the problem

Comment: thank you! helped this code :`final  String [] descriptions =  new  String []  {
                getResources().getString(R.string.ml350),
                getResources().getString(R.string.ml400),
                getResources().getString(R.string.ml600),
                getResources().getString(R.string.ml800),
                getResources().getString(R.string.ml1000)};`

Answer (score 1):

```
<string-array name="system">
   <item>300</item>
   <item>400</item>
   <item>600</item>
   <item>800</item>
   <item>1000</item>
</string-array>
```

you can create an array in your xml and then call

```
 String[] descriptions  = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_string_array) //in example is system
```

Comment: getResources() is not a static method. You need an instance of the View to call it ...

Answer (score 0):

`R.strings.300` returns `int` type but your array requires String type, that's why you get error.